# Lumen - Expect Authentication Error In Test

Tags: php, json, laravel, lumen

When I try to access an end point of the API without a token I get an error, as I should. For my test I want to test I can't access the an end point without a token. The error that appears is:

```
Invalid JSON was returned from the route. Perhaps an exception was thrown?
```

How would I test to expect this error?

Comment: Maybe `assertResponseStatus(403)` ?

Comment: It was actually assertResponseStatus(401) but thank you.